# Termination because of NSEexception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

This is what is in my .m file, from xcode.
 My main goal is to have a button play a sound(not at the same time) when it has 2 sound files attached and a randomizer so it doesn't play the same sound twice or wouldn't likely do it twice. I run code and when I click on the Yes button an lldb NSEsception error occurs. Ive looked around for the lldb exception error but the solution I found was to go into view-controller an delete anything with a yellow exclamation mark;which didn't not solve the issue..

```
       #import "ViewController.h"
      #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController ()
 @end
  @implementation ViewController : UIViewController
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {

  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

   - (IBAction)Yes{
  NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray
                       arrayWithObjects:
                       @"yes.mp3",
                       @"yes 3.mp3",

                       nil];

 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<=[array count]; i++)
  {

    NSInteger rand=(arc4random() %1);
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i
               withObjectAtIndex:rand];
  }
    NSString *sound = [array objectAtIndex:i];
   AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:         

   [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:sound ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];


   [audioPlayer play];
  }

 @end
```

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four issues. Your loop range, the calculation of the random value, and the array index usage after the loop, and you specify the sound file's extension twice.

The loop and random value should be:

```
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    NSInteger rand = arc4random_uniform(array.count);
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:rand];
}
```

1. Notice the `<=` is now `<`.
2. Your calculation of the random number always returned 0.

It's unclear what you want to get the `sound` value after the loop. As written, you try to access using `i` which will be too large. You need to specify a value in the range `0` to `array.count - 1`.

If you just want the 1st (now random) value from the array, use:

```
NSString *sound = [array firstObject];
```

**Update:**

After realizing you really just want to play one of the two sounds randomly, I think your code can be simplified to:

```
- (IBAction)Yes {
    NSInteger rand = arc4random_uniform(2);
    NSString sound = rand == 0 ? @"yes" : @"yes 3";
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:sound withExtension:@"mp3"];

    AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: where do I specify this value in the pathforresource? Cause the goal is to have the button be lcick then the sound be played either 1 or 2, then when clicked again either 1 or 2(since its 2 sounds) so its kinda random.

Comment: still getting the exception. Is it ok to put sound in the Pathforresource?

Comment: See my update. It's MUCH easier. Also, please learn to use some whitespace in your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: U sir are a genius, however the sound isnt playing when the button is clicked, I tested whether putting the mp3 files in a folder would still play and it did so why wouldn't they play now that no exception is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=0;i<=[array count]; i++)`

should be turned into

`for(i=0;i<[array count]; i++)`

otherwise you get out of the array bounds.

And you should also double check the range of values the `rand`variable and see if it does never exceed the array size - 1.
so for instance:

`NSInteger rand=MIN((arc4random() %1), array.count - 1);`

Comment: Still get the error after clicking the button. I think it has something to do with using the string sound in the path for resource but I am not sure what else to put at the path if the sound string doesn't go there to tell the avaudio where the array an whats in it is so it can be played?

Comment: can you paste the full exception? @cloudhalo

Comment: here is the full exception                                         2014-09-21 18:33:12.377 Strogg[59125:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: so the problem is exactly that: an array out of bound :) make sure that neither i nor `rand`are exceeding `array.count - 1`